# Python Matplotlib; animating a user-defined shape

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to do something, but I do not know how to start. I am hoping for a few suggestions on that.

I want to plot a 3D object,:
[image: https://www.staff.ncl.ac.uk/j.p.goss/symmetry/D2d_3D.gif]

So, it's a simple cuboid with a regular pattern on the faces.

With that cuboid, I want to make an animation that can rotate it.

The only thing that springs to mind (due to my ignorance) is using a scatter plot and this object composed of points. This doesn't sound ideal, and I'm sure that matplotlib can do better than my bad initial guess.

Any suggestions?

Comment: mayavi http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html hope it might help you

Comment: That's the documentation to an alternative of matplotlib, right? Another documentation doesn't exactly help me, but thanks all the same.

Comment: What kind of pattern are you thinking about?, maybe this question is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19349904/displaying-true-colour-2d-rgb-textures-in-a-3d-plot

Comment: @NoelSegura, regular geometric patterns like the chess tiles in the block.  The link seems interesting - it hints at some very specific plot_surface usage.

Comment: I think the easiest way forward - especially because we have very clear geometrical shapes - is to use e.g. contourf and draw each part separately. I'll go mess about with that for a bit. In principle, rotation can be done by translating the center to zero, rotating it and then translating it back - so that is doable.

Comment: https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/11/24/simple-3d-visualization-in-matplotlib/
I'm going to see if I can use this, or edit it. It seems nice, anyway.