# How to orient matplotlib ax objects to plot consecutively along a timeseries line (affine_transform, mtransform)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot

I am trying to create heatmaps (and scatter plots eventually) for data in a time series.  I would like to orient them in a way that shows they are on a linear timeline.

How can I use either `matplotlib Affine2D` or `scipy.ndimage.affine_transform` to achieve this?  Ideally, I would like to be able to adjust the following angles: (1) The angle of the timeline (i.e. where T = 1, T = 2, and T = 3 are in example 1); and (2) The angle where the heatmap meets the line in (1)

The examples I found are dependent on `im = ax.imshow` which are not the case for my examples.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Get iris data
X_iris = pd.DataFrame({'sepal_length': {'iris_0': 5.1, 'iris_1': 4.9, 'iris_2': 4.7, 'iris_3': 4.6, 'iris_4': 5.0, 'iris_5': 5.4, 'iris_6': 4.6, 'iris_7': 5.0, 'iris_8': 4.4, 'iris_9': 4.9, 'iris_10': 5.4, 'iris_11': 4.8, 'iris_12': 4.8, 'iris_13': 4.3, 'iris_14': 5.8, 'iris_15': 5.7, 'iris_16': 5.4, 'iris_17': 5.1, 'iris_18': 5.7, 'iris_19': 5.1, 'iris_20': 5.4, 'iris_21': 5.1, 'iris_22': 4.6, 'iris_23': 5.1, 'iris_24': 4.8, 'iris_25': 5.0, 'iris_26': 5.0, 'iris_27': 5.2, 'iris_28': 5.2, 'iris_29': 4.7, 'iris_30': 4.8, 'iris_31': 5.4, 'iris_32': 5.2, 'iris_33': 5.5, 'iris_34': 4.9, 'iris_35': 5.0, 'iris_36': 5.5, 'iris_37': 4.9, 'iris_38': 4.4, 'iris_39': 5.1, 'iris_40': 5.0, 'iris_41': 4.5, 'iris_42': 4.4, 'iris_43': 5.0, 'iris_44': 5.1, 'iris_45': 4.8, 'iris_46': 5.1, 'iris_47': 4.6, 'iris_48': 5.3, 'iris_49': 5.0, 'iris_50': 7.0, 'iris_51': 6.4, 'iris_52': 6.9, 'iris_53': 5.5, 'iris_54': 6.5, 'iris_55': 5.7, 'iris_56': 6.3, 'iris_57': 4.9, 'iris_58': 6.6, 'iris_59': 5.2, 'iris_60': 5.0, 'iris_61': 5.9, 'iris_62': 6.0, 'iris_63': 6.1, 'iris_64': 5.6, 'iris_65': 6.7, 'iris_66': 5.6, 'iris_67': 5.8, 'iris_68': 6.2, 'iris_69': 5.6, 'iris_70': 5.9, 'iris_71': 6.1, 'iris_72': 6.3, 'iris_73': 6.1, 'iris_74': 6.4, 'iris_75': 6.6, 'iris_76': 6.8, 'iris_77': 6.7, 'iris_78': 6.0, 'iris_79': 5.7, 'iris_80': 5.5, 'iris_81': 5.5, 'iris_82': 5.8, 'iris_83': 6.0, 'iris_84': 5.4, 'iris_85': 6.0, 'iris_86': 6.7, 'iris_87': 6.3, 'iris_88': 5.6, 'iris_89': 5.5, 'iris_90': 5.5, 'iris_91': 6.1, 'iris_92': 5.8, 'iris_93': 5.0, 'iris_94': 5.6, 'iris_95': 5.7, 'iris_96': 5.7, 'iris_97': 6.2, 'iris_98': 5.1, 'iris_99': 5.7, 'iris_100': 6.3, 'iris_101': 5.8, 'iris_102': 7.1, 'iris_103': 6.3, 'iris_104': 6.5, 'iris_105': 7.6, 'iris_106': 4.9, 'iris_107': 7.3, 'iris_108': 6.7, 'iris_109': 7.2, 'iris_110': 6.5, 'iris_111': 6.4, 'iris_112': 6.8, 'iris_113': 5.7, 'iris_114': 5.8, 'iris_115': 6.4, 'iris_116': 6.5, 'iris_117': 7.7, 'iris_118': 7.7, 'iris_119': 6.0, 'iris_120': 6.9, 'iris_121': 5.6, 'iris_122': 7.7, 'iris_123': 6.3, 'iris_124': 6.7, 'iris_125': 7.2, 'iris_126': 6.2, 'iris_127': 6.1, 'iris_128': 6.4, 'iris_129': 7.2, 'iris_130': 7.4, 'iris_131': 7.9, 'iris_132': 6.4, 'iris_133': 6.3, 'iris_134': 6.1, 'iris_135': 7.7, 'iris_136': 6.3, 'iris_137': 6.4, 'iris_138': 6.0, 'iris_139': 6.9, 'iris_140': 6.7, 'iris_141': 6.9, 'iris_142': 5.8, 'iris_143': 6.8, 'iris_144': 6.7, 'iris_145': 6.7, 'iris_146': 6.3, 'iris_147': 6.5, 'iris_148': 6.2, 'iris_149': 5.9}, 'sepal_width': {'iris_0': 3.5, 'iris_1': 3.0, 'iris_2': 3.2, 'iris_3': 3.1, 'iris_4': 3.6, 'iris_5': 3.9, 'iris_6': 3.4, 'iris_7': 3.4, 'iris_8': 2.9, 'iris_9': 3.1, 'iris_10': 3.7, 'iris_11': 3.4, 'iris_12': 3.0, 'iris_13': 3.0, 'iris_14': 4.0, 'iris_15': 4.4, 'iris_16': 3.9, 'iris_17': 3.5, 'iris_18': 3.8, 'iris_19': 3.8, 'iris_20': 3.4, 'iris_21': 3.7, 'iris_22': 3.6, 'iris_23': 3.3, 'iris_24': 3.4, 'iris_25': 3.0, 'iris_26': 3.4, 'iris_27': 3.5, 'iris_28': 3.4, 'iris_29': 3.2, 'iris_30': 3.1, 'iris_31': 3.4, 'iris_32': 4.1, 'iris_33': 4.2, 'iris_34': 3.1, 'iris_35': 3.2, 'iris_36': 3.5, 'iris_37': 3.6, 'iris_38': 3.0, 'iris_39': 3.4, 'iris_40': 3.5, 'iris_41': 2.3, 'iris_42': 3.2, 'iris_43': 3.5, 'iris_44': 3.8, 'iris_45': 3.0, 'iris_46': 3.8, 'iris_47': 3.2, 'iris_48': 3.7, 'iris_49': 3.3, 'iris_50': 3.2, 'iris_51': 3.2, 'iris_52': 3.1, 'iris_53': 2.3, 'iris_54': 2.8, 'iris_55': 2.8, 'iris_56': 3.3, 'iris_57': 2.4, 'iris_58': 2.9, 'iris_59': 2.7, 'iris_60': 2.0, 'iris_61': 3.0, 'iris_62': 2.2, 'iris_63': 2.9, 'iris_64': 2.9, 'iris_65': 3.1, 'iris_66': 3.0, 'iris_67': 2.7, 'iris_68': 2.2, 'iris_69': 2.5, 'iris_70': 3.2, 'iris_71': 2.8, 'iris_72': 2.5, 'iris_73': 2.8, 'iris_74': 2.9, 'iris_75': 3.0, 'iris_76': 2.8, 'iris_77': 3.0, 'iris_78': 2.9, 'iris_79': 2.6, 'iris_80': 2.4, 'iris_81': 2.4, 'iris_82': 2.7, 'iris_83': 2.7, 'iris_84': 3.0, 'iris_85': 3.4, 'iris_86': 3.1, 'iris_87': 2.3, 'iris_88': 3.0, 'iris_89': 2.5, 'iris_90': 2.6, 'iris_91': 3.0, 'iris_92': 2.6, 'iris_93': 2.3, 'iris_94': 2.7, 'iris_95': 3.0, 'iris_96': 2.9, 'iris_97': 2.9, 'iris_98': 2.5, 'iris_99': 2.8, 'iris_100': 3.3, 'iris_101': 2.7, 'iris_102': 3.0, 'iris_103': 2.9, 'iris_104': 3.0, 'iris_105': 3.0, 'iris_106': 2.5, 'iris_107': 2.9, 'iris_108': 2.5, 'iris_109': 3.6, 'iris_110': 3.2, 'iris_111': 2.7, 'iris_112': 3.0, 'iris_113': 2.5, 'iris_114': 2.8, 'iris_115': 3.2, 'iris_116': 3.0, 'iris_117': 3.8, 'iris_118': 2.6, 'iris_119': 2.2, 'iris_120': 3.2, 'iris_121': 2.8, 'iris_122': 2.8, 'iris_123': 2.7, 'iris_124': 3.3, 'iris_125': 3.2, 'iris_126': 2.8, 'iris_127': 3.0, 'iris_128': 2.8, 'iris_129': 3.0, 'iris_130': 2.8, 'iris_131': 3.8, 'iris_132': 2.8, 'iris_133': 2.8, 'iris_134': 2.6, 'iris_135': 3.0, 'iris_136': 3.4, 'iris_137': 3.1, 'iris_138': 3.0, 'iris_139': 3.1, 'iris_140': 3.1, 'iris_141': 3.1, 'iris_142': 2.7, 'iris_143': 3.2, 'iris_144': 3.3, 'iris_145': 3.0, 'iris_146': 2.5, 'iris_147': 3.0, 'iris_148': 3.4, 'iris_149': 3.0}, 'petal_length': {'iris_0': 1.4, 'iris_1': 1.4, 'iris_2': 1.3, 'iris_3': 1.5, 'iris_4': 1.4, 'iris_5': 1.7, 'iris_6': 1.4, 'iris_7': 1.5, 'iris_8': 1.4, 'iris_9': 1.5, 'iris_10': 1.5, 'iris_11': 1.6, 'iris_12': 1.4, 'iris_13': 1.1, 'iris_14': 1.2, 'iris_15': 1.5, 'iris_16': 1.3, 'iris_17': 1.4, 'iris_18': 1.7, 'iris_19': 1.5, 'iris_20': 1.7, 'iris_21': 1.5, 'iris_22': 1.0, 'iris_23': 1.7, 'iris_24': 1.9, 'iris_25': 1.6, 'iris_26': 1.6, 'iris_27': 1.5, 'iris_28': 1.4, 'iris_29': 1.6, 'iris_30': 1.6, 'iris_31': 1.5, 'iris_32': 1.5, 'iris_33': 1.4, 'iris_34': 1.5, 'iris_35': 1.2, 'iris_36': 1.3, 'iris_37': 1.4, 'iris_38': 1.3, 'iris_39': 1.5, 'iris_40': 1.3, 'iris_41': 1.3, 'iris_42': 1.3, 'iris_43': 1.6, 'iris_44': 1.9, 'iris_45': 1.4, 'iris_46': 1.6, 'iris_47': 1.4, 'iris_48': 1.5, 'iris_49': 1.4, 'iris_50': 4.7, 'iris_51': 4.5, 'iris_52': 4.9, 'iris_53': 4.0, 'iris_54': 4.6, 'iris_55': 4.5, 'iris_56': 4.7, 'iris_57': 3.3, 'iris_58': 4.6, 'iris_59': 3.9, 'iris_60': 3.5, 'iris_61': 4.2, 'iris_62': 4.0, 'iris_63': 4.7, 'iris_64': 3.6, 'iris_65': 4.4, 'iris_66': 4.5, 'iris_67': 4.1, 'iris_68': 4.5, 'iris_69': 3.9, 'iris_70': 4.8, 'iris_71': 4.0, 'iris_72': 4.9, 'iris_73': 4.7, 'iris_74': 4.3, 'iris_75': 4.4, 'iris_76': 4.8, 'iris_77': 5.0, 'iris_78': 4.5, 'iris_79': 3.5, 'iris_80': 3.8, 'iris_81': 3.7, 'iris_82': 3.9, 'iris_83': 5.1, 'iris_84': 4.5, 'iris_85': 4.5, 'iris_86': 4.7, 'iris_87': 4.4, 'iris_88': 4.1, 'iris_89': 4.0, 'iris_90': 4.4, 'iris_91': 4.6, 'iris_92': 4.0, 'iris_93': 3.3, 'iris_94': 4.2, 'iris_95': 4.2, 'iris_96': 4.2, 'iris_97': 4.3, 'iris_98': 3.0, 'iris_99': 4.1, 'iris_100': 6.0, 'iris_101': 5.1, 'iris_102': 5.9, 'iris_103': 5.6, 'iris_104': 5.8, 'iris_105': 6.6, 'iris_106': 4.5, 'iris_107': 6.3, 'iris_108': 5.8, 'iris_109': 6.1, 'iris_110': 5.1, 'iris_111': 5.3, 'iris_112': 5.5, 'iris_113': 5.0, 'iris_114': 5.1, 'iris_115': 5.3, 'iris_116': 5.5, 'iris_117': 6.7, 'iris_118': 6.9, 'iris_119': 5.0, 'iris_120': 5.7, 'iris_121': 4.9, 'iris_122': 6.7, 'iris_123': 4.9, 'iris_124': 5.7, 'iris_125': 6.0, 'iris_126': 4.8, 'iris_127': 4.9, 'iris_128': 5.6, 'iris_129': 5.8, 'iris_130': 6.1, 'iris_131': 6.4, 'iris_132': 5.6, 'iris_133': 5.1, 'iris_134': 5.6, 'iris_135': 6.1, 'iris_136': 5.6, 'iris_137': 5.5, 'iris_138': 4.8, 'iris_139': 5.4, 'iris_140': 5.6, 'iris_141': 5.1, 'iris_142': 5.1, 'iris_143': 5.9, 'iris_144': 5.7, 'iris_145': 5.2, 'iris_146': 5.0, 'iris_147': 5.2, 'iris_148': 5.4, 'iris_149': 5.1}, 'petal_width': {'iris_0': 0.2, 'iris_1': 0.2, 'iris_2': 0.2, 'iris_3': 0.2, 'iris_4': 0.2, 'iris_5': 0.4, 'iris_6': 0.3, 'iris_7': 0.2, 'iris_8': 0.2, 'iris_9': 0.1, 'iris_10': 0.2, 'iris_11': 0.2, 'iris_12': 0.1, 'iris_13': 0.1, 'iris_14': 0.2, 'iris_15': 0.4, 'iris_16': 0.4, 'iris_17': 0.3, 'iris_18': 0.3, 'iris_19': 0.3, 'iris_20': 0.2, 'iris_21': 0.4, 'iris_22': 0.2, 'iris_23': 0.5, 'iris_24': 0.2, 'iris_25': 0.2, 'iris_26': 0.4, 'iris_27': 0.2, 'iris_28': 0.2, 'iris_29': 0.2, 'iris_30': 0.2, 'iris_31': 0.4, 'iris_32': 0.1, 'iris_33': 0.2, 'iris_34': 0.2, 'iris_35': 0.2, 'iris_36': 0.2, 'iris_37': 0.1, 'iris_38': 0.2, 'iris_39': 0.2, 'iris_40': 0.3, 'iris_41': 0.3, 'iris_42': 0.2, 'iris_43': 0.6, 'iris_44': 0.4, 'iris_45': 0.3, 'iris_46': 0.2, 'iris_47': 0.2, 'iris_48': 0.2, 'iris_49': 0.2, 'iris_50': 1.4, 'iris_51': 1.5, 'iris_52': 1.5, 'iris_53': 1.3, 'iris_54': 1.5, 'iris_55': 1.3, 'iris_56': 1.6, 'iris_57': 1.0, 'iris_58': 1.3, 'iris_59': 1.4, 'iris_60': 1.0, 'iris_61': 1.5, 'iris_62': 1.0, 'iris_63': 1.4, 'iris_64': 1.3, 'iris_65': 1.4, 'iris_66': 1.5, 'iris_67': 1.0, 'iris_68': 1.5, 'iris_69': 1.1, 'iris_70': 1.8, 'iris_71': 1.3, 'iris_72': 1.5, 'iris_73': 1.2, 'iris_74': 1.3, 'iris_75': 1.4, 'iris_76': 1.4, 'iris_77': 1.7, 'iris_78': 1.5, 'iris_79': 1.0, 'iris_80': 1.1, 'iris_81': 1.0, 'iris_82': 1.2, 'iris_83': 1.6, 'iris_84': 1.5, 'iris_85': 1.6, 'iris_86': 1.5, 'iris_87': 1.3, 'iris_88': 1.3, 'iris_89': 1.3, 'iris_90': 1.2, 'iris_91': 1.4, 'iris_92': 1.2, 'iris_93': 1.0, 'iris_94': 1.3, 'iris_95': 1.2, 'iris_96': 1.3, 'iris_97': 1.3, 'iris_98': 1.1, 'iris_99': 1.3, 'iris_100': 2.5, 'iris_101': 1.9, 'iris_102': 2.1, 'iris_103': 1.8, 'iris_104': 2.2, 'iris_105': 2.1, 'iris_106': 1.7, 'iris_107': 1.8, 'iris_108': 1.8, 'iris_109': 2.5, 'iris_110': 2.0, 'iris_111': 1.9, 'iris_112': 2.1, 'iris_113': 2.0, 'iris_114': 2.4, 'iris_115': 2.3, 'iris_116': 1.8, 'iris_117': 2.2, 'iris_118': 2.3, 'iris_119': 1.5, 'iris_120': 2.3, 'iris_121': 2.0, 'iris_122': 2.0, 'iris_123': 1.8, 'iris_124': 2.1, 'iris_125': 1.8, 'iris_126': 1.8, 'iris_127': 1.8, 'iris_128': 2.1, 'iris_129': 1.6, 'iris_130': 1.9, 'iris_131': 2.0, 'iris_132': 2.2, 'iris_133': 1.5, 'iris_134': 1.4, 'iris_135': 2.3, 'iris_136': 2.4, 'iris_137': 1.8, 'iris_138': 1.8, 'iris_139': 2.1, 'iris_140': 2.4, 'iris_141': 2.3, 'iris_142': 1.9, 'iris_143': 2.3, 'iris_144': 2.5, 'iris_145': 2.3, 'iris_146': 1.9, 'iris_147': 2.0, 'iris_148': 2.3, 'iris_149': 1.8}})
y_iris = pd.Series({'iris_0': 'setosa', 'iris_1': 'setosa', 'iris_2': 'setosa', 'iris_3': 'setosa', 'iris_4': 'setosa', 'iris_5': 'setosa', 'iris_6': 'setosa', 'iris_7': 'setosa', 'iris_8': 'setosa', 'iris_9': 'setosa', 'iris_10': 'setosa', 'iris_11': 'setosa', 'iris_12': 'setosa', 'iris_13': 'setosa', 'iris_14': 'setosa', 'iris_15': 'setosa', 'iris_16': 'setosa', 'iris_17': 'setosa', 'iris_18': 'setosa', 'iris_19': 'setosa', 'iris_20': 'setosa', 'iris_21': 'setosa', 'iris_22': 'setosa', 'iris_23': 'setosa', 'iris_24': 'setosa', 'iris_25': 'setosa', 'iris_26': 'setosa', 'iris_27': 'setosa', 'iris_28': 'setosa', 'iris_29': 'setosa', 'iris_30': 'setosa', 'iris_31': 'setosa', 'iris_32': 'setosa', 'iris_33': 'setosa', 'iris_34': 'setosa', 'iris_35': 'setosa', 'iris_36': 'setosa', 'iris_37': 'setosa', 'iris_38': 'setosa', 'iris_39': 'setosa', 'iris_40': 'setosa', 'iris_41': 'setosa', 'iris_42': 'setosa', 'iris_43': 'setosa', 'iris_44': 'setosa', 'iris_45': 'setosa', 'iris_46': 'setosa', 'iris_47': 'setosa', 'iris_48': 'setosa', 'iris_49': 'setosa', 'iris_50': 'versicolor', 'iris_51': 'versicolor', 'iris_52': 'versicolor', 'iris_53': 'versicolor', 'iris_54': 'versicolor', 'iris_55': 'versicolor', 'iris_56': 'versicolor', 'iris_57': 'versicolor', 'iris_58': 'versicolor', 'iris_59': 'versicolor', 'iris_60': 'versicolor', 'iris_61': 'versicolor', 'iris_62': 'versicolor', 'iris_63': 'versicolor', 'iris_64': 'versicolor', 'iris_65': 'versicolor', 'iris_66': 'versicolor', 'iris_67': 'versicolor', 'iris_68': 'versicolor', 'iris_69': 'versicolor', 'iris_70': 'versicolor', 'iris_71': 'versicolor', 'iris_72': 'versicolor', 'iris_73': 'versicolor', 'iris_74': 'versicolor', 'iris_75': 'versicolor', 'iris_76': 'versicolor', 'iris_77': 'versicolor', 'iris_78': 'versicolor', 'iris_79': 'versicolor', 'iris_80': 'versicolor', 'iris_81': 'versicolor', 'iris_82': 'versicolor', 'iris_83': 'versicolor', 'iris_84': 'versicolor', 'iris_85': 'versicolor', 'iris_86': 'versicolor', 'iris_87': 'versicolor', 'iris_88': 'versicolor', 'iris_89': 'versicolor', 'iris_90': 'versicolor', 'iris_91': 'versicolor', 'iris_92': 'versicolor', 'iris_93': 'versicolor', 'iris_94': 'versicolor', 'iris_95': 'versicolor', 'iris_96': 'versicolor', 'iris_97': 'versicolor', 'iris_98': 'versicolor', 'iris_99': 'versicolor', 'iris_100': 'virginica', 'iris_101': 'virginica', 'iris_102': 'virginica', 'iris_103': 'virginica', 'iris_104': 'virginica', 'iris_105': 'virginica', 'iris_106': 'virginica', 'iris_107': 'virginica', 'iris_108': 'virginica', 'iris_109': 'virginica', 'iris_110': 'virginica', 'iris_111': 'virginica', 'iris_112': 'virginica', 'iris_113': 'virginica', 'iris_114': 'virginica', 'iris_115': 'virginica', 'iris_116': 'virginica', 'iris_117': 'virginica', 'iris_118': 'virginica', 'iris_119': 'virginica', 'iris_120': 'virginica', 'iris_121': 'virginica', 'iris_122': 'virginica', 'iris_123': 'virginica', 'iris_124': 'virginica', 'iris_125': 'virginica', 'iris_126': 'virginica', 'iris_127': 'virginica', 'iris_128': 'virginica', 'iris_129': 'virginica', 'iris_130': 'virginica', 'iris_131': 'virginica', 'iris_132': 'virginica', 'iris_133': 'virginica', 'iris_134': 'virginica', 'iris_135': 'virginica', 'iris_136': 'virginica', 'iris_137': 'virginica', 'iris_138': 'virginica', 'iris_139': 'virginica', 'iris_140': 'virginica', 'iris_141': 'virginica', 'iris_142': 'virginica', 'iris_143': 'virginica', 'iris_144': 'virginica', 'iris_145': 'virginica', 'iris_146': 'virginica', 'iris_147': 'virginica', 'iris_148': 'virginica', 'iris_149': 'virginica'})

# Get correlation matrix
data = OrderedDict()
for species, X in X_iris.groupby(y_iris):
    data[species] = X.corr()
print("Species:", list(data.keys()), "\n", "Correlation matrix shapes:", list(map(lambda df:df.shape, data.values())), sep="")
# Species:['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
# Correlation matrix shape:[(4, 4), (4, 4), (4, 4)]

with plt.style.context("seaborn-white"):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(13,3), ncols=len(data), sharey=True)
    for i, (species, df_corr) in enumerate(data.items()):
        sns.heatmap(df_corr, vmin=-1, vmax=1, cmap=plt.cm.seismic_r, ax=axes[i], cbar= (i == len(data) - 1), edgecolor="white", linewidth=1)
```

#### Here's my heatmaps:

[image]

I would like to rotate these ways.

#### Example 1 (angle around 60 degrees):

[image: How]

#### Example 2 (angle 0 degrees):

[image]

Eventually, I will try and connect the axes together with lines such as in the bottom figure but first I need to find out how to oritent these pre-existing `ax` objects.

EDIT: After posting this, I found https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/affine_image.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.1.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.affine_transform.html but I haven't figured out how to properly use this with multiple ax and line them up in this way.

I found a [function](https://teneto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/teneto.plot.graphlet_stack_plot.html#teneto.plot.graphlet_stack_plot) that can do this to some degree (example #2 figure) but I wasn't able to reverse engineer the source code.

Comment: Maybe a useful starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19476891/2912349

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion, it looks like that is using a 3D plot and maya.  Interesting approach.

Comment: Do you want to produce a 2D or a 3D plot?

Comment: I was thinking a 2D plot since they can render much quicker.

Answer (score 3):

The trick here is to create images of each 'plot' and render them on the same 'axis'.  As per the example given in the documentation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/affine_image.html

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import transforms
from PIL import Image

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()

for i in range(5):
    data = numpy.random.rand(4,4)
    im = ax.imshow(data, extent=[0, 10, 0, 4])
    transform = transforms.Affine2D().skew_deg(0, 30).scale(0.5, 1).translate(5*i,0)
    trans_data = transform + ax.transData
    im.set_transform(trans_data)
    ax.set_ylim(0,10)
    ax.set_xlim(0,25)

pyplot.show()
```

This obviously uses random data which you will have to replace by your own heatmaps, and tinker with the transforms, etc.[image: Heatmap]

To generalise this somewhat, we need to create an image of the 'figure'.  This can be done very clumsily with a function such as:

```
def create_plot_img():
    f, ax = pyplot.subplots()
    x = numpy.arange(4)
    y = numpy.random.rand(4)
    ax.plot(x,y, )
    f.canvas.draw()
    w,h = f.canvas.get_width_height()
    arr = numpy.fromstring(f.canvas.tostring_argb(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    arr.shape = (w,h,4)
    arr = numpy.roll(arr, 3, axis = 2)
    return Image.frombytes( "RGBA", (w,h), arr.tostring())
```

Again this will need much tinkering to make it fit your needs.[image: Line Plot]

EDIT:
The first four lines of the 'create_plot_img' function, in this example is just generic code to produce a very simple line-plot with random data.  This can be replaced by any matplotlib plot/scatter/3Dplot/ etc you wish.

To use this in the main code (first code block), simply alter the line:

```
data = numpy.random.rand(4,4)
```

to:

```
data = create_plot_img()
```

EDIT #2:
Complete code to plot the example given in the comments below:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib import transforms
from PIL import Image

def create_plot_img(i):
    f, ax = pyplot.subplots()
    x = numpy.random.RandomState(i).normal(size=50)
    y = x**2
    ax.plot(x,y, )
    f.canvas.draw()
    w,h = f.canvas.get_width_height()
    arr = numpy.fromstring(f.canvas.tostring_argb(), dtype=numpy.uint8)
    arr.shape = (w,h,4)
    arr = numpy.roll(arr, 3, axis = 2)
    return Image.frombytes( "RGBA", (w,h), arr.tostring())    

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()

for i in range(5):
    data = create_plot_img(i)
    im = ax.imshow(data, extent=[0, 10, 0, 4])
    transform = transforms.Affine2D().skew_deg(0, 30).scale(0.5,1).translate(5*i,0)
    trans_data = transform + ax.transData
    im.set_transform(trans_data)
    ax.set_ylim(0,10)
    ax.set_xlim(0,25)
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Can this be generalized to any matplotlib plot? For example, a scatter plot ?

Comment: Is it possible to get the "images" from `ax` with `get_children()`?

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work with the `plt.plot` https://i.imgur.com/zOmTFcp.png  Does the above method with `Affine2D` only work with the heatmaps returned from `imshow`?

Comment: I've updated my answer to demonstrate how to implement your example.  I must stress that you need to tinker quite a lot with axes decoration to give reasonable results.  However in principle this will do what's required.